# Use of Spark pictures

Tags: artistic-works

In my thesis dissertation, I need to use a picture to illustrate how Spark clusters are built. Ideally, I would like to reuse this picture for illustrating Spark components: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/img/cluster-overview.png

Is it allowed? Who am I supposed to ask permission otherwise?

FYI my thesis is purely academic and does not target any company or business usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [hosting website](https://spark.apache.org/) makes it clear in the footer that the content is "*Copyright © 2018 The Apache Software Foundation, Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0*", so you may use that diagram under [those terms](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).